# How to pass values between functional components in ReactJS- output [object Object]?

Tags: java, reactjs, components, react-props, react-functional-component

I recently learned how to pass props in functional components that were located in different .js files. Now I'm having trouble passing a prop in functional components that are in the same .js file.

I would like to get `member_id` from the GET request in my first function `GetMemID` and use it to set `member_id` of my useState in my second function `Transactions`.

I know my GET request is working because I am able to see the data after I inspect my code.

With my code so far, I am getting "[object Object]".

This is my code so far:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import  SigninNavBar from '../components/SigninNavBar.js';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

var currentDate = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

function GetMemID() {

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

const options = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("http://#####/api/members/get/", options)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
      setError(response);
    }
    response.json().then(data => {
      setDetails(data);
    });
  });
}, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {details.map(item => (
         <Transaction member_id={item.member_id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}


function Transaction({member_id}) {

  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState({member_id, category:'', description:'', amount:0}); 
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({id:0, mmeber_id:0, group:"", username:""});

  //catch any changes made to member_id
  useEffect(() => {
    setTrans(trans => ({
      ...trans, 
      member_id,
    }));
  }, [member_id]);
  
  //GET rerquest to get transaction memberID
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    },
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://#####/api/members/get/", options)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log(response.status);
        setError(response);
      }
      response.json().then(data => {
        setDetails(data);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  //POST request to API for transaction
  const optionPOST = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`
    },
    body:JSON.stringify(trans)
  }

  const createTransaction = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("http://34.94.76.5/api/transactions/post/", optionPOST)
    .then((response) => console.log('reponse: ' + response.json()))
    .then((message) => console.log('message: ' + message))
  }

  if (error) {
    return (<Redirect to="/Signin" />);
  } else{
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <SigninNavBar />
        <form>
          <div className="form-horizantal">
            <fieldset>
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12"><p>{currentDate}</p></label>
              </div>
              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Member ID</p>
                  <input type="text" name="member_id" defaultValue={trans.member_id} readOnly/>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Category</p>
                  <input type="text" name="category" value={trans.category} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, category: e.target.value })} />
                  
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Description</p>
                  <input type="text" name="description" value={trans.description} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, description: e.target.value })} />
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="form-group row">
                <label className="col-md-12">
                  <p>Amount</p>
                  <input type="text" name="amount" value={trans.amount} onChange={e => setTrans({ ...trans, amount: e.target.value })} />
                </label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" onClick={createTransaction}>Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Transaction;
```

Comment: where are you getting an `[object Object]`?

Comment: Where is there any `GetMemID` function? Where do you 'With my code so far, I am getting "[object Object]".'?

Comment: @DrewReese, Sorry about that! I edited it to include the function.

Comment: @JorgeKunrath `[object Object]` is the output for this line of code
`<input type="text" name="member_id" defaultValue={trans.member_id} readOnly/>`

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You are rendering an object which isn't valid in JSX in React. You are passing what looks to be a value:

```
<Transaction state={item.member_id} />
```

But then pack this into an object in `Tranaction` when setting the initial state value:

```
function Transaction({ state }) {
  ...
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState({
    member_id: { state }, // <-- packed prop value into object
    category:'',
    description:'',
    amount:0,
  });
```

So when rendering the input you are passing an object as the input's default value:

```
<input
  type="text"
  name="member_id"
  defaultValue={trans.member_id} // <-- object value!!
  readOnly
/>
```

## Solution

`state` ***is*** the `item.member_id` value, so no need to pack it into an object. Since the state in the parent is updated asynchronously you will need to react to component updates. Use an `useEffect` hook to "watch" for changes on the `state` prop.

```
function Transaction({ state }) {
  ...
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState({
    member_id: state, // <-- set as passed prop value
    category:'',
    description:'',
    amount:0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrans(trans => ({
      ...trans, // <-- copy previous state
      member_id: state, // <-- update member_id from props
    }));
  }, [state]);
```

I suggest naming the prop more accurately, i.e. name it `member_id`, then setting initial state is a bit cleaner.

```
<Transaction member_id={item.member_id} />
```

...

```
function Transaction({ member_id }) {
  ...
  const [trans, setTrans] = useState({
    member_id, // <-- set as passed prop value via object shorthand notation
    category:'',
    description:'',
    amount:0,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrans(trans => ({
      ...trans, // <-- copy previous state
      member_id, // <-- update member_id from props
    }));
  }, [member_id]);
```

Comment: Thank you for an in-depth explanation! I do understand it a lot more. However, after make the corrections you suggested, I still have no luck. It got rid of the `[object Object]` output, but now, I'm not getting an output at all.

Comment: @KassandraI Oops, yeah, the state in the parent is updated asynchronously so the children would need to implement a lifecycle hook to react to changes to props (and state if necessary). I've updated my answer which should hopefully clear that up.

Comment: I see, I will have to research asynchronous states. My code is still not displaying the `member_id` but I can definitely say I've learned a lot about passing props.